# EMV - SELECT not getting PDOL

Tags: java, smartcard, apdu, emv

ok so i selected the "1PAY.SYS.DDF01" PSE and got this response:
("00 A4 04 00 0E 31 50 41 59 2E 53 59 53 2E 44 44 46 30 31")
"61 1E", so i did the GET Response command and got this output:
("00 C0 00 00 1E")
["6F 1C 84 0E 31 50 41 59 2E 53 59 53 2E 44 44 46 30 31 A5 0A 88 01 01 5F 2D 04 68 65 65 6E"]

[TLV decode 1PAY.SYS.DDF01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSCmV.png)

then i moved to READ RECORDS command (with the sfi=1) and got this:
("00 B2 01 0C 00")
and got the response of:
"6C 1E"
SO I did it again like this:
("00 B2 01 0C 1E")
and got the response of:
["70 1C 61 1A 4F 07 A0 00 00 00 03 10 10 50 0C 56 69 73 61 20 50 72 65 70 61 69 64 87 01 01"]

[TLV decode sfi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQqhI.png)

after that when i tried to do READ RECORDS of the second record:
("00 B2 02 0C 00")
I got this response: "6A 83" (record not found)

now I tried to SELECT FILE of the aid we got:
"61 25" (do a GET RESPONSE with this le)
then i did the GET RESPONSE:
("00 C0 00 00 25")
and got this:
["6F 23 84 07 A0 00 00 00 03 10 10 A5 18 50 0C 56 69 73 61 20 50 72 65 70 61 69 64 87 01 01 5F 2D 04 68 65 65 6E"]
[TLV decode AID][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7AJ2.png)

as you can see I didn't got any PDOL, can anyone help me?

Comment: @DeniDin Just a note -- you should take more time writing your question the next time you ask. And you definitely should read the [EMV Books](https://www.emvco.com/emv-technologies/contact/). You might find [javaemvreader](https://github.com/sasc999/javaemvreader) really helpful. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

PDOL is optional in ADF selection response data (see EMV 4.3 Book 1, Table 45).

In this case an empty tag '83' is sent in `GET PROCESSING OPTIONS`, citing EMV 4.3 Book 3, section 6.5.8.3:

> The data field of the command message is a data object coded according to the
>   PDOL provided by the ICC, as defined in section 5.4, and is introduced by the tag
>   '83'. **When the data object list is not provided by the ICC, the terminal sets the
>   length field of the template to zero.** Otherwise, the length field of the template is
>   the total length of the value fields of the data objects transmitted to the ICC.

`GET PROCESSING OPTIONS` is then: `80 A8 00 00 02 83 00 00`

Answer (score 0):

Just like @vlp stated, you can not read the file yet. You have to send GET PROCESSING OPTIONS” (GPO) command to retrieve the Application Interchange Profile (AIP) and the Application File Locator(AFL).

It is from the AFL that you can start reading data off the card.

This resource explains your exact situation; https://blog.saush.com/2006/09/08/getting-information-from-an-emv-chip-card/